# "IO Error:Connection refused (Connection refused)" rejection occurring for simple database app

Tags: java, database-connection

This app is not displaying any results from the database, to the console as it should. The rejection says "IO Error:Connection refused (Connection refused)".

It is not a fire wall issue (firewall is off). The ports match and are correct and the server is definitely up and running.

```
 package javaapplication4;

 import java.sql.*;

 public class JavaApplication4  {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   String data = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample";
   try (
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
           data, "app", "APP");
       Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {

       Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");

        ResultSet rec = st.executeQuery(
            "select CUSTOMER_ID, NAME, CITY, STATE " +
            "from APP.CUSTOMER " +
            "order by CUSTOMER_ID");
        while (rec.next()) {
            System.out.println("CUSTOMER_ID:\t"
                + rec.getString(1));
            System.out.println("NAME:\t" + rec.getString(2));
            System.out.println("CITY:\t" + rec.getString(3));
            System.out.println("STATE:\t" + rec.getString(4));
            System.out.println();
        }
        st.close();
    } catch (SQLException s) {
        System.out.println("SQL Error: " + s.toString() + " "
            + s.getErrorCode() + " " + s.getSQLState());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString()
            + e.getMessage());
    }
     }
 }
```

The program should display the name, city and state of 4 database records to the console of netbeans. Instead it is giving the previously described rejection.

Comment: Can you show „netstat -tln | grep 1527“ output? The error is very surely showing that you target the wrong port or address. Also try 127.0.0.1 or the public ip instead of localhost in data url.

Comment: What happens when you run this: "telnet localhost 1527"?

Comment: I have tried putting my IP address and 127.0.0.1 in place of "localhost" with the same rejection occurring. I am not sure what you guys mean by "show „netstat -tln | grep 1527“ output" and "run telnet localhost 1527", I am a beginner, I thought telnet was a separate app I can get to test the server. The server says "started and ready to accept connections on port 1527" in netbeans when I start it.

Comment: Your `Class.forName` is BTW not needed or too late in the code.

Comment: I have resolved this issue. I am not sure what exactly happened but I simply deleted the project and created a new project and the issue was resolved.